# Removing item from the list and error list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
L=[1,2,3,4,5]

x=input('Enter a value to remove from list: ')
while x!='quit':
    for i in range(0,len(L)):
        if L[i]==int(x):
            L.pop(i)
    x=input('Enter a value to remove from list: ')
```

Hello, I get an error message, which is "list index out of range", and I suppose that it stems from change in list size, but I cannot find how to fix it. Is there a solution without using list comprehension?

Answer (score 0):

When you take the input again, make `i = 0` again. This will solve the error I think.
Something like this:

```
L=[1,2,3,4,5]

x=input('Enter a value to remove from list: ')
while x!='quit':
    for i in range(0,len(L)):
        if L[i]==int(x):
            L.pop(i)
    x=input('Enter a value to remove from list: ')
    i = 0
```

This will make sure the next time, i starts with 0 and then searches the list again for the input x. List index out of range error will be fixed this way.

Another thing you can do to make the code cleaner is just use the shortcut to search if element is in the list or not:

```
L=[1,2,3,4,5]

x=input('Enter a value to remove from list: ')
while x!='quit':
    if x in L:
        L.pop(x)
    x=input('Enter a value to remove from list: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is using `for` loop for removal from the list when you do that, the variable `i` goes to `len(L)-1` while the list only should go up to `len(L)-2` as one element is now removed, instead use the `index` function, try this :

```
L=[1,2,3,4,5]

try:
    x=int(input('Enter a value to remove from list: '))
except:
    print("Input Error")
    exit()
while x!='quit':
    try:
        L.pop(L.index(x))
    except:
        pass
    try:
        x=int(input('Enter a value to remove from list: '))
    except:
        print("Input Error")
        exit()
```

Additionally, you need to convert the input to a string, and the `try` function is used for integrity check.

Answer (score 0):

Good luck!

```
input_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

while True:
    try:
        user_input = input('Enter a value to remove from list: ')

        if user_input == 'quit':
            print("Thanks for your participation!")
            break

        if int(user_input) in input_list:
            input_list.remove(int(user_input))
            print('Removed!')
        else:
            print("Item not present!")

    except:
        print("Invalid input!")
    
    if len(input_list) == 0:
        print('List is empty now!')
        break
```